# CSS Descendent Selector After Hover Psuedo Class Only Works in Chrome

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am creating a menu where I want the menu items to fade in when I hover on them and fade out when I hover off of them. I am using CSS 3. This code works in Chrome and in no other browsers. It seems to be the line in the CSS where there is a direct descendent selector after the hover psuedo class that is causing the problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainMenu">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="dir">
     Menu Item
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
li.dir > ul{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

li.dir:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me on Firefox, IE10, Safari and Chrome... you probably have some other markup or styles that are interfering with what you have given here.

Comment: That is exactly right. There were some conflicting styles. Thanks!

Comment: Question already answered in comments.